# laradock can't run shell_exec('git pull')?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laradock

This is the first time to add a gitlab webhook in my laravel application running in laradocker.

- First, run docker up:

  docker-compose up -d nginx redis mysql
- Second, add webhook in my gitlab project

  point to laravel website http://example.com/deploy/
- Third, laravel add router and Controller

  ```
  // web.php
  Route::post('/deploy', 'DeployController@index')->name('deploy');

  // DeployController
  //........
  $result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/git pull");
  logger('success result: ' . $result);
  //.........
  ```

It doesn't work!

**which step go wrong?**

I found php-fpm has logs like:

```
[22-Jan-2018 07:46:46] WARNING: [pool www] child 7 said into stderr: "sh: 1: /usr/bin/git: not found"
```

I am a new docker learner, it will helpfull if you leaves some comment or advise, thanks!

Comment: You need to install git with `apt-get install git`

Comment: In my workspace container, git has installed. You mean in php-fpm container also have to intall git again ?

Comment: What happens when you execute `git pull` in the php-fpm container?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, git  is not installed or it is not in your $PATH.

```
/usr/bin/git: not found
```

Comment: How to include workspace docker container git in php-fpm docker container $PATH ? Or just install again in php-fpm container ?